# PostGIS Geography datatype

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have been searching about geography datatype and the type of data it can hold. Can the geography type have 3D and 4D data like **POINTZ**. I know that there is a geometry type that can have 3D and 4D but whenever I search for geography, I am getting mixed results. SOme say that you can use 3d in geography and some say that you can't.
Can anyone clarify this for me?

I have tried creating a column with the following and it worked:

**pointz_location geography(POINTZ);**

Comment: The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Create_Geography_Tables) is fairly clear _"The modifier supports coordinate dimensionality restrictions by adding suffixes: Z, M and ZM"_. What is less clear is which function will use or even preserve these extra dimensions.